# No puedo instalar el package.js de Laravel en Node JS

Tags: nodejs, laravel

Mi intención es instalar el package que tiene Laravel en Node.js.

Este es el contenido de mi fichero package.js:

```
{
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
      "dev": "gulp watch",
      "prod": "gulp --production"
   },
"devDependencies": {
    "bootstrap-sass: "^3.3.7",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "jquery": "^3.1.0",
    "laravel-elixir": "^6.0.0-9",
    "laravel-elixir-vue": "0.1.4",
    "laravel-elixir-webpack-official": "^1.0.2",
    "lodash": "^4.14.0",
    "vue": "^1.0.26",
    "vue-resource": "^0.9.3"
   }
}
```

En la terminal de Node.js pongo el comando `npm install` y me marca este error:

> ```
> c:\xampp\htdocs\[proyecto]> npm install
> npm ERR! code E400
> npm ERR! 400 Bad Request: gulp@^3.9.1
>
> ...
> ```

Ya he intentado:

- reinstalar Node.js.
- eliminar las carpeta de `node_modules` de mi proyecto varias veces
  porque no me instalaba el `laravel-elixir`.

¿Qué más puedo hacer?

Comment: El error dice que es instalando `gulp^3.9.1` y al parecer no tiene que ver con `laravel`, puedes intentar solo instalar gulp en un proyecto vacio, o quizas con otra version?.

Comment: No solo es gulp, sino en todas las dependencias. Inente crear un nuevo proyecto e instalar de nuevo el package.js pero persiste el error

Answer (score 2):

Pude hacer la instalación de los módulos de node sin problema alguno. Lo único que veo raro en lo que estás posteando es que tienes un error en el package.json

Te faltan comillas en el **"bootstrap-sass": "^3.3.7"**

```
{
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
      "dev": "gulp watch",
      "prod": "gulp --production"
   },
"devDependencies": {
    "bootstrap-sass": "^3.3.7",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "jquery": "^3.1.0",
    "laravel-elixir": "^6.0.0-9",
    "laravel-elixir-vue": "0.1.4",
    "laravel-elixir-webpack-official": "^1.0.2",
    "lodash": "^4.14.0",
    "vue": "^1.0.26",
    "vue-resource": "^0.9.3"
   }
}
```

Saludos!

Comment: Ammm, no son las comillas. Dime como puedo instalar las dependencias como dices

Comment: Solamente copié tu package.json en un directorio, lo corregí y le di npm install y funcionó, fue todo lo que hice.

Comment: Ya lo hice amigo, hastatuve que crear un nuevo proyecto pero el error persiste